# Apache poi XWPFRun style

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

How can I get style for XWPFRun used apache poi in Java?

Part of my OpenXml file:

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00D0130C">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rStyle w:val="10"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Видит</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I try get run style, but class XWPFRun class has no method for this.
http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html

I can get paragraph style. But the paragraph within which Run is not applied style. The style is applied to Run(see xml part). How can i get Run style.

```
    for (XWPFParagraph p : wd.getParagraphs()) {
        System.out.println(p.getText());
        for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
                    Integer i = r.getFontSize();
                    r.getParagraph().getStyle();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You likely will need to post some code about what you already tried. Did you take a look at the Javadoc of Apache POI to see what it offers in this area?

Comment: Yes, i look Javadoc. I edited the question.

Comment: A paragraph will contain one or more runs. But a run contains no paragraph. In fact according to Apache POI documentation getParagraph returns the parent paragraph. Also getParagraph is deprecated.

Comment: The XWPFRun itself has several methods for styling information, but none of them are called "getStyle": http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html Methods like XWPFRun.isItalic() and XWPF.getFontSize() return the styling for the Run if specified in the CTR, and for the Paragraph if not specified for the Run itself. If you want all the styling info, you should be able to cycle through all those methods. Is there a particular component to the style that's not covered by them?